# C++ - copying vector in foreach gives "No matching function to call for std::vector<int>::push_back(std::vector<int>&)"

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I have the following function:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> solve(int t){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    result.push_back(std::vector<int>(2*t,0));
    //CODE TO fill up result[0]
    return result;
}
```

And when I write the following code to get results:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> results(4);
for(int t = 0; t < 4; ++t){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> cols = solve(t);
    if(cols.size() > 0){
        for(std::vector<int> col: cols){
            results[t].push_back(col);            
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
src/pricing.cpp:33:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::push_back(std::vector<int>&)’
 results[t].push_back(col);
```

From what I understand the range based for is creating `col` as a reference. What I don't understand is `push_back` being able to insert `col`. Why is this happening and what's the best way to insert `col` into `results[t]`?

Comment: You are trying to push a `std::vector<int>` as element into a `std::vector<int>`, which has elements of type `int`. What was your intended behavior of that line?

Comment: You're right. I'm don't know how I didn't see it. For what I want I would need to use 3 std::vector nested. I'm gonna need to rethink my strategy, as I think this will be too much ugly

Comment: If you make use of `auto` or `using` type aliases, then it isn't going to be any worse, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col` is a `vector<int>`.

You're attempting to add that to an element of `results`, which can only hold `int`s.

That's what the compiler is telling you.